# Theorem of the Mean

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be compact and $f:V\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be continuous (and Lipschitz). Suppose that the Jacobian $f_x$ of $f$ is continuous on $V$. What allows us to conclude the following?

> Let $x,x'\in V$. There exists a matrix $\Gamma = (\Gamma_{ij})$ such
>   that $$f(x') - f(x) = (f_x(x) + \Gamma)(x' - x)$$ where, given any
>   $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta$, which depends on $\epsilon$
>   such that $|\Gamma| = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} {|\Gamma_{ij}|} < \epsilon$ if
>   $|x'-x|<\delta$.

What I know is that since $f_x$ is continuous on $V$, that is, all its partial derivatives are continuous on $V$, we have that $f$ is differentiable there. The statement above is actually very similar to the definition of differentiability for vector-valued functions; what puzzles me is where the $\Gamma$ comes from. The book I am reading says it's an application of the Theorem of the Mean but I am not sure which one it is referring to. I have also tried using the mean-value theorem for real-valued functions to no avail.

EDIT: 
I am practically finished with the problem above. Only now, it turns out that I need something more. Is it possible to choose a $\delta$ that works for any choice of $x$? The text I'm reading says that this has something to do with the uniform continuity of $f_x$.

In case you're interested, I need this in understanding page 26 (Proof of Theorem 7.2) of *Theory of differential equations*, E.A. Coddington and N. Levinson

Comment: I'd try to look at Taylor expansion: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables)

Comment: I have tried doing this using Taylor's theorem. I was successful in obtaining some $\Gamma$ from there that works. But I have two problems: (a) Taylor's theorem requires that the second partials exist but we only have here that the first partials are continuous. (b) Assuming that I can obtain that $\Gamma$ from Taylor's theorem, how does it follow that $|\Gamma| \to 0$ as $|x'-x| \to 0$? I'm given to understand that $f_x$ being uniformly continuous plays a role here.

Comment: Your function is $\mathcal C^1(V,\mathbb R^n)$ (continuous, partial derivatives are continuous), hence you can apply Taylor's theorem with Peano form of remainder. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) look for statements in 1D for Peano form and generalisations for multi-dimensioned case. Note for Peano you don't need higher derivatives.

Comment: Oh that's great, thanks! :)

Comment: @TZakrevskiy By the way, I don't think I need this but I'm asking out of curiosity. In the wiki article that you linked (on Taylor's theorem), the multivariate version requires $f$ to be $k$ times differentiable at a point. But is this sufficient? Don't we need the $k$th order partials to be continuous so that the mixed partials of order $k$ have a common value?

Comment: The derivability in the point implies that mixed partials have common value (note that the definition of derivability uses the linear approximation, not partial derivatives).

Comment: Is that so? I'm afraid this is new to me. Is this easy to show? If you have any suggested reference I can use on this, I would appreciate it. Thanks. :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't give you any references in English, I learned these things in other languages. For the proof, I think it's possible to do it by recurrence. You can always ask another question here at math.SE, I'm sure people are able to provide you with good books/links with the correct proof.

Comment: I think they used the $n \times n$ matrix $\Gamma$ as an error term, which doesn't have any rigorous specific form...just intuition.